# Python: os.join.path()

Tags: python, string

I used os.join.path() to load image in a folder. But I found the function cannot give accurate path when it is used in defining another function in some cases. For example:

```
def Myfuncion(something)
    desiredPath = os.path.join('myPath','apple.jpeg')
    #desiredPath = os.path.normpath(os.path.join('myPath','apple.jpeg')) 

    print desiredPath
    return
```

When I implement the function, the printed result of the path is:

```
 myPath\apple.jpeg
```

It is illegal for image loading. But os.path.join() works well in Pythonconsole.

How to make the path generated in such function definition have double backslashes?

Also, it is noted os.path.normpath also cannot work well sometimes. For example:

```
 os.path.normpath('myPath\apple')
```

It should give the result:

```
 myPath\\apple
```

But instead, it results in:

```
 'myPath\x07pple'
```

How come??

Comment: You are aware that a string defined with double backslashes (that's called escaped) will show with only one backslash when printed? And that `'\x07'` is equivalent to `'\a'`?

Comment: Yes! I use print only for debugging, since I found the image at the path is not loaded properly. I used Image.open() to load the image, and then saved it to another folder

Comment: Please do independent research on how backslashes function in strings.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I got it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`\a` is equivalent to `\x07`. (See escape sequence part in [String and bytes literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals).)

```
>>> '\a'
'\x07'
```

You need to escape `\` to mean backslash literally:

```
>>> '\\a'
'\\a'
>>> print('\\a')
\a
```

or, use raw string literal:

```
>>> r'\a'
'\\a'
>>> print(r'\a')
\a
```

Comment: But the path with single backlishes is illegal for python to load an image.

Comment: @jingweimo, My point is that `os.path.join('myPath','apple.jpeg') == 'myPath\\apple.jpeg'` (in other word, `os.path.join('myPath','apple.jpeg') == 'myPath\apple.jpeg'`

Comment: @jingweimo path with single backslash is legal but it makes problem when there are special chars like `\n`, `\t`, `\a`, `\u`, etc. So it is safer to use  \\ or / (even on Windows) or `os.path.join()`

Comment: @jingweimo, Please check escape sequence part of documentation. I provided the link to the documentation in the answer.

Comment: Thanks! How to deal with that case of special chars?

Comment: @jingweimo, As I mentioned in the answer, escape backslash (`\ `) or use raw string literal.

Comment: @jingweimo use \\ or / or `os.path.join()` and you will no have problem with special chars .

Comment: You should actually have only on backslash, so your comment is not correct. You only have to give two backslashes when defining a (non raw) string in code.

Comment: You @peter I will post my complete codes tomorrow

Comment: R@ Kraus D. I do use \\ when I feed a root path in the function. But os.path.join change it somehow into that with \

Comment: @falsetru I see the reason. Thanks